# How do you create multiple pages when using Reactjs? Is there a specific function to carry this out?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What function do I have to use to create multiple pages on React. Is there a type of link or something thank can direct me to pages in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

React is meant to be used in single page application, so by default it do not provide such functionality. But if you want to add routing in it then you can use react-router.

What react-router will do is just swap you browser link to look like it is on a new page and replace content in body.

Hope this will make you help to understand the use of react.

Comment: I disagree with your opening statement. React is defined as a library for building user interfaces, and you could serve React JS files, where & when needed, along with regular HTML on a 'normal' (read, non-SPA) website.

It is however, indeed, common practice to use react-router within an SPA to create the illusion of multiple pages, but it's not an imperative.

Comment: You are one hundred percent right but I was trying to answer the question what you asked about creating pages with react.

Comment: if you want to create pages then you need to go for react router but if you are asking about the components then you can create as many as you want as widgets or whatever you wanna call it.